# Need to validate the length of a variable and perform an action accordingly in unix

Tags: linux, unix, ksh

We have a variable with a value in it. My requirement is if the length of the variable is greater than 0(zero) do something else do another thing

Step1: I have a variable with some value say

```
    abc="asdfg"
```

Step2: Determine the length of the variable

```
    xyz=`echo ${#abc}`
```

Step3: Now I use a If loop to determine if the variable has value greater than 0

```
    if [[$xyz -gt 0]]; then
    echo "success"
    else
    echo "fail"
    fi
```

I am having a problem at step 3. it does not give me a success message. need assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [[$xyz -gt 0]]; then
```

should be:

```
if [[ $xyz -gt 0 ]]; then
```

You need spaces between the brackets and parameters.

Comment: Please have another look at the solutions from @abasterfield: `[ -n ... ]` and @HermanTorjussen `(( ${#...} ))`.  They perform the test on the actual variable, making it more concise.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a variable is not zero length with -n

```
if [ -n $abc ]; then
 echo "success"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily like this:

```
VAR=""
if [ "$VAR" ]; then echo Full; fi
VAR="a"
if [ "$VAR" ]; then echo Full; fi
Full
```

You are missing some spaces around your square brackets.

Comment: I was trying to show you that you don't need to get the length first. If you just test the string itself (not its length) you get the same result and it's easier.

Comment: intresting!! let me check this out

Answer (score 1):

A short and fast solution to do this is to use `${#var}` directly in an if-test:

```
if (( ${#abc} )); then
    # ...
fi
```

This removes the unnecessary command-substituion that you have there and tests directly on the length. If the length is zero then the test fails.

Comment: trendy.. let me try this